# Unable to create a Java class in the existing framework in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij

Unable to create a Java class in the existing framework in IntelliJ. Java is already installed but still not able to create Java class. Also tried reimporting and reinstalling IntelliJ but still seeing the same issue.

[image: Here I am trying to create a new java class but there is no option available]

Comment: Can you check the Build tab? Any irregularities?

Comment: Screenshots are bad. Photographs are worse. A photograph _of a screenshot_ is baffling.

Answer (score -1):

You may try below hit and try, it might help you to get resolved the issue:

**Java SDK:**
Ensure that the Java SDK is correctly configured in IntelliJ IDEA. Go to File > Project Structure > SDKs to check if the SDK is listed and the paths are correct.
Under Project Settings > Project, check if the Project SDK is set to the correct Java version.

**Project Structure:**
Navigate to File > Project Structure > Modules, and make sure the module SDK is set correctly.
Check if the src folder is correctly marked as Sources in the Modules section. If not, right-click the src folder in the Project view and select Mark Directory as > Sources Root.

**IntelliJ Configuration Files:**
Invalid or corrupted configuration files can cause this issue. Locate the .idea folder in your project directory and delete it (make sure to back it up first). Then reopen IntelliJ and re-import your project.

**Plugins:**
Sometimes plugins can interfere with project setup. Try disabling recently installed plugins to see if that resolves the issue.

**IntelliJ Cache:**
Clearing the cache can sometimes resolve these types of issues. Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and select both Invalidate and Restart.

**Reimport Maven/Gradle Project:**
If you're using Maven or Gradle, try reimporting the project. Click on the Maven Projects or Gradle tab on the right side of the IDE and click the Refresh button.

**File Types:**
Check under Settings > Editor > File Types and ensure that the .java extension is not associated with a different file type.

**Permissions:**
Make sure you have the proper permissions in the directory you're working in. Lack of permissions can sometimes lead to such issues.

**IntelliJ Logs:**
Check the IntelliJ logs for any errors that can give you more information about the issue. You can find logs under Help > Show Log in Explorer/Finder.